# Hot zones on emails marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, history-tracking, email-studio

Do we have a view on Salesforce marketing cloud, to see the hot zones on every email sent ?

Answer (score 1):

The closest think to this is the Click activity report found in [tracking](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/tracking/). It will display clicks on links by percentage